# AEM Publisher 6.5 - No bin Directory

Tags: installation, aem, startup, bin, crx

I am starting AEM in publish mode using the quickstart jar:

```
java -jar cq-publish-p4506.jar
```

Under the **crx-quickstart** directory, i see only one directory, **repository**. There is no **bin** directory created under it

```
crx-quickstart/
      repository/
```

What can i do to make AEM create the bin directory with start/stop scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

`java -jar <CQ_JAR_PATH> -unpack -v`

This will extract for you.

Then edit the `start` or `quickstart` files to set the run mode to publish and port to `4506`.

You can then use the start/stop/quickstart scripts to start AEM.

Answer (score 0):

The `bin` directory is under `crx-quickstart`, not under `repository`.

Comment: My problem is - only one directory was generated under crx-quickstart, which is “repository”. No other directory was generated

Comment: Oh, I got it, not even the /logs directory? What JDK are you using?